# Changing a php "echoed" div attribute with php

Tags: php, dom, attributes

I'm using PHP to echo a content stored on my database.  The content is a DIV carrying any type of data.

The problem is that I don't know the ID and I have some problems with these DIVs if I try to display them more than once.

So, the idea is to modify the DIV id each time I'd like to display them.
Something like this:

```
<?php modify_div_id($data,"id-456"); ?>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean to say you have div tags literally stored in your database?

Comment: yes ... i have some fields where we can find divs with their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly, but i think it works.

```
function modify_div_id( $data, $new_id ) {
  return preg_replace( '/(<div[^>]+?id=)("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', '$1$2' . $new_id . '$4', $data );
}
```

The best way to go is to use an XML parser to change the attribute.

**Edit:** the function assumes the div to already have an id attribute.

**Edit #2**
It seems to be working!

```
jwandborg@sophie:~$ cat | php -r "eval( file_get_contents('php://stdin') );"
function modify_div_id( $data, $new_id ) {
  return preg_replace( '/(<div[^>]+?id=)("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', '$1$2' . $new_id . '$4', $data );
}
echo modify_div_id('<div pajas="pajas" id="fisk">Innehåll</div>', 'nytt_id');

# Result: <div pajas="pajas" id="nytt_id">Innehåll</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is worded kind of vague.

First off, the `id` attribute for HTML elements must be unique, so echoing a unique `id` is appropriate (you can also use a `class`).

If you've queried your database and received back, say, an array containing an `id` and the content, you can use the function as follows:

```
function modify_div_id($data, $id) {
  echo "<div id='$id'>$data</div>";
}
```

Just an example.